# unable to define an ID when using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the React Hook called useEffect to update in my functional component.

I need to pass the CITY_ID, but I can't figure out where to put it.

I have this so far:

```
const { zooData, setZooData } = useState();

const fetchAnimalData = async (id) => {
    const result = await axios("api/animal/" + id);
    return result;
};

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetchAnimalData(CITY_ID);
        setZooData(response);
    }
    fetchData();
}, [CITY_ID]);
```

And then later, I want to use it like this:

```
newZooAnimal = {zooData};
```

But it keeps telling me that "CITY_ID" is not defined.

Is there a proper place to define or put it?

Thanks!

Comment: where from you are getting CITY_ID? from props?

Comment: @bakar_dev Yes it's being retrieved via props passed to it.  thanks

Comment: so you are doing `const {CITY_ID} = props` in your code? Also, you must be getting warning to include `fetchAnimalData ` function as dependency of useEffect i believe

Comment: Can you put the whole component code in the question? From this chunk everything seems fine.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal I did const CITY_ID = props.zoo;  zoo has my CITY_ID.  But maybe I need to do {CITY_ID} instead of just CITY_ID?

Comment: if your zoo is an object which contains `CITY_ID ` as key, then your need to do {CITY_ID}

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal thanks, I didn't realize that.  That fixed it!